# $5$ and $11$ divides a perfect square $abc0ac$. What is the number?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, square-numbers

> $5$ and $11$ divides a perfect square $abc0ac$. What is the number?

I started this way - expressing the number as $(10^5+10)a+(10^4)b + (10^3+1)c$
Which fooled me. How can I start?
**P.S**: This is a problem from BdMO-2016 regionals.

Comment: 5 is a divisor, so the last digit must be 0 or 5.  If c is 0, a must be 0, which is false, so c must be 5. Hence, a must be 2. So your task is to find out b.

Comment: @Huang Why a must be 0 if c = 0? Didn't get this.. :|

Comment: since $5$ is a divisor of this number

Comment: @RezwanArefin since it's a perfect square. It the ones digit is 0, the ones digit of its root must be 0, so the tens and ones digits are both 0 of that number.

Comment: @Huang Thanks ! Got it

Comment: Observe it must be that $\;b+c=2a+c\iff b=2a\;$ (why?)

Comment: @DonAntonio I didn't get this. So I accepted a Wrong solution. Thanks ! :(

Comment: A natural number is a multiple of $\;11\;$ iff (the sum of its digits in even poisition) minus (the sum of its digits in odd position) is a multiple of $\;11\;$ . With this and knowing $\;c=5\implies a=2\;$ you can solve this at once.

Comment: @DonAntonio why?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Oh, that's a nice little proof. You can check it somewhere (google it), but you can verify it with the first few multiples of 11, say up to 20 or 30...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $25$ divides N it follows $ac \in \{ 00, 25, 50, 75\}$. Because $11$ divides N it follows that the alternating sum of the digits in the number is divisible by 11, therefore $11 | 2a -b$.

Now just take each possibility for $ac$

Comment: Already got solution from Huang's comment. This is also a nice solution :D

Comment: @RezwanArefin No, you didn't...and you **should have checked** that supposed solution is wrong!

Comment: @DonAntonio Yep. ! I also got the wrong solution .. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I will post an answer for completion.

If the number is divisible by $5$ then $c=5$ or $c=0$. It cannot equal $0$ by Huang's comment. Therefore $c=5$ and because a perfect square ending in $5$ necessarily ends in $25$ we know that $a=2$. 

If a number is divisible by $11$ then the alternating sum of its digits: $a-b+c-0+a-c=2a-b=4-b=11n$ (i.e. the sum must be a multiple of $11$). Because $0\le b \le 9$, then $n$ can only equal $0$, from which we know that $b=4$ and the number equals $$245025=495^2$$